# Selected option doesn't show in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why when i use javascript code to set selected value on my dropdown list, attribute 'selected' does not set in html, but in layout all right.

```
$("#my_dropdown").val('some_value');

$("#my_dropdown option[value='"+some_value+"']").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `prop()`:

```
$("#my_dropdown option[value='" + some_value + "']").prop("selected", true);
```

However, the first method in your question (setting the `val()`) is better practice.

Comment: shouln't be .prop("selected", "selected");?

Comment: @KnF the `selected` attribute, according to the specification, requires no value so you can specify whatever you like. I prefer `true` as the value should be a boolean IMO

Comment: you're right.. is .prop("selected", true) for the prop method.. and .attr("selected", "selected") for the attr method.. is the same though....

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between attributes and properties.

An attribute is what's in the HTML code that the element was created from, i.e. it's the initial value.

The property is the current value, so you can change a property without affecting the corresponding attribute.

Using `val` in the `select` element will set the `selected` property of the option, but it won't change the `selected` attribute.

In jQuery there are `attr` and `prop` methods to set the attribute and the property, respectively.